How to stop a Cypress test when a certain element is found
I have a Cypress test that was working fine. Its operation was stopped for a while and now we need to reactivate it, but it is not working anymore.
Here is the code
cy.get('[data-cy="content-wrapper"]').then(inputRow => {
            if (inputRow.find('[data-cy="error-message-text"]').length) {
                if (inputRow.find('[data-cy="MarketAvailableRuleFailure"]').length) {
                    cy.log('Outcome not available');
                    cy.then(() => this.skip()); // stop test
                }
                if (inputRow.find('[data-cy="MinValueRuleFailure"]').length) {
                    cy.log('Value is too small');
                    cy.then(() => this.skip()); // stop test
                }
               
            }
        });

I'm getting this error message: "_this.skip is not a function"
error message
It seems that .skip is no longer working as it used to.
I tried to use cy.then(() => cy.state('test').skip()) , as described here:
text
Unfortunately cy.state is deprecated.
Can someone help me with this?

It's just a typo, the screenshot does not agree with you code - there is an underscore in front of this.
Also make sure the block that code is in uses function() {} not () => {}, otherwise this is undefined.
And cy.state() is not deprecated, cy.state('text').skip() works. You should actually test it rather than going by what your read.
